# PHP select option values when use with echo

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to show details in a table and show list of values in drop down list. the values are shown in table but drop down list is not showing the values although the values exists and when i save it in session and print it, it appears at the top . Also I have problem in using name of select. when i click on button and wants to read the post value of the option, it gives me error as shown in figure

[image]

here is the code:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($dr_ide);$i=$i+5)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> Dr. " . $dr_namee[$i] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+3] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+4] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>  <select  name='perr' >
                    <option name='perr' selected=selected>Choose one</option>";
                    foreach($Names as $name) {
                        echo"<option name='perr' value=";
                             $name ;
                            echo "> ";
                            $_SESSION["tt"]=$name;
                            $name;
                            echo"</option>";


                    } 
                    echo "</select></td>";
        //echo "<td>" . $dayse[$i] . "</td>";
        //echo "<td>" . $timing[$i] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}

    echo $_SESSION["tt"];

    if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){ 
        echo $_POST['perr'];
    }
```

Here is my full page code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Expert System </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 </head>
<body>
<div >
  <table id="cells2" border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="5"  font size="6">

<tr>
<th><img id="header2"  src="images/Kuwait_University_Logo.jpg" > </th>
<th>KUWAIT UNIVERSITY</th>
</tr>
</table>
<div class='back1'>

<table border='1' align='center' id='customers' >
<?php
 require "init.php";
session_start();

    global $con,$users,$dr_id,$sub_id,$dr_name,$sub_name,$days,$fav,$timing;
    global $dr_ide,$dr_namee,$sub_namee,$dayse,$fave,$timinge;


        $query= "SELECT * FROM subjects_current where subjects_current.sub_ID NOT IN (SELECT test.subject_id from test)";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ) // User doesn't exist
        echo "Subjects doesn't exist!";
    else { 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

            $IDs[]=$row['sub_ID'];
            $Names[]=$row['Name'];
            //echo $row['Name'];
        }
    }


    $query= "SELECT * FROM test order by dr_id";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ) // User doesn't exist
        echo "Subjects doesn't exist!";
    else { echo "
        <tr>
            <th>Professor Name</th>
            <th>First Choice</th>
            <th>Second Choice</th>
            <th>Third Choice</th>
            <th>Fourth Choice</th>
            <th>Fifth Choice</th>
            <th>Update Subject</th>

        </tr>";

       $r=0;
       $f=0;
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $dr_ide[$f]=$row['dr_id'];
            $dr_namee[$f]=$row['dr_name'];
            $sub_namee[$f]=$row['sub_name'];
            $dayse[$f]=$row['days'];
            $timinge[$f]=$row['timing'];
            $fave[$f]=$row['fav'];

            //echo "<tr>";
            //echo "<td> Dr. " . $dr_namee[$f] . "</td>";
            //echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$f] . "</td>";
            //echo "<td>" . $fave[$f] . "</td>";
            //echo "<td>" . $dayse[$f] . "</td>";
            //echo "</tr>";
            //$r++;
            $f++;
        }
        //for($i=0;$i<count($Names);$i=$i+5)
        //{
        for($i=0;$i<count($dr_ide);$i=$i+5)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td> Dr. " . $dr_namee[$i] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+1] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+2] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+3] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+4] . "</td>";

            echo "<td>  <select  name='perr' >
                        <option name='perr' selected=selected>Choose one</option>";
                        foreach($Names as $name) {
                             echo"<option name='perr' value='$name'>$name</option>";

                        }                            
                        echo "</select></td>";
            //echo "<td>" . $dayse[$i] . "</td>";
            //echo "<td>" . $timing[$i] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

    echo $_SESSION["tt"];

    if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){ 
        echo $_POST['perr'];
    }

?>
</table>
<form method='post' action='edit_subjects.php'>
            <input ID="btn2" name="confirm"  type="submit" value="Home">

            </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: You are right but I just built all my project in this way and i have two days for delivery so i can't rebuilt it in other way, so if u can help me with this work i will be happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `name='perr'` from `<options>` and change `foreach()` like below:-

```
foreach($Names as $name) {
    echo"<option value='$name'>$name</option>";
}
```

***Do change in  your code like this:-***

```
echo "<form method='post' action='edit_subjects.php'>"; //add before while
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $dr_ide[$f]=$row['dr_id'];
            $dr_namee[$f]=$row['dr_name'];
            $sub_namee[$f]=$row['sub_name'];
            $dayse[$f]=$row['days'];
            $timinge[$f]=$row['timing'];
            $fave[$f]=$row['fav'];

            $f++;
        }
        for($i=0;$i<count($dr_ide);$i=$i+5)
        {
            $dr_nam = $dr_namee[$i];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td> Dr. " . $dr_namee[$i] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+1] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+2] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+3] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+4] . "</td>";

            echo "<td><select  name='perr[$dr_nam]' >
                        <option name='perr' selected=selected>Choose one</option>";
                        foreach($Names as $name) {
                             echo"<option name='perr' value='$name'>$name</option>";

                        }                            
                        echo "</select></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo"<input ID='btn2' name='confirm'  type='submit' value='Home'></form>"; //add just after while code ended
```

Comment: this solve the first problem and the values appear, but when i wants to read the post value it give me error "undefined index"

Comment: you are the king of PHP, thanks for ur help it works now

Comment: @SalehRefaai  glad to help you:):)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<td>  <select  name='perr' >
      <option name='perr' selected='selected'> Choose one </option>";
      foreach($Names as $name) {
         echo"<option name='perr' value='". $name ."'> ". $name ." </option>";
      } 
echo "</select></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo the names like this:

```
foreach($Names as $name) {
    echo "<option value=";
    echo $name ;
    echo "> ";
    $_SESSION["tt"]=$name;
    echo $name;
    echo"</option>";
}
```

And put the table inside the form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Expert System </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 </head>
<body>
<div >
  <table id="cells2" border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="5"  font size="6">

<tr>
<th><img id="header2"  src="images/Kuwait_University_Logo.jpg" > </th>
<th>KUWAIT UNIVERSITY</th>
</tr>
</table>
<div class='back1'>
<form method='post' action='edit_subjects.php'>
<table border='1' align='center' id='customers' >
<?php
 require "init.php";
session_start();

    global $con,$users,$dr_id,$sub_id,$dr_name,$sub_name,$days,$fav,$timing;
    global $dr_ide,$dr_namee,$sub_namee,$dayse,$fave,$timinge;


        $query= "SELECT * FROM subjects_current where subjects_current.sub_ID NOT IN (SELECT test.subject_id from test)";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ) // User doesn't exist
        echo "Subjects doesn't exist!";
    else { 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

            $IDs[]=$row['sub_ID'];
            $Names[]=$row['Name'];
            //echo $row['Name'];
        }
    }


    $query= "SELECT * FROM test order by dr_id";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ) // User doesn't exist
        echo "Subjects doesn't exist!";
    else { echo "
        <tr>
            <th>Professor Name</th>
            <th>First Choice</th>
            <th>Second Choice</th>
            <th>Third Choice</th>
            <th>Fourth Choice</th>
            <th>Fifth Choice</th>
            <th>Update Subject</th>

        </tr>";

       $r=0;
       $f=0;
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $dr_ide[$f]=$row['dr_id'];
            $dr_namee[$f]=$row['dr_name'];
            $sub_namee[$f]=$row['sub_name'];
            $dayse[$f]=$row['days'];
            $timinge[$f]=$row['timing'];
            $fave[$f]=$row['fav'];

            //echo "<tr>";
            //echo "<td> Dr. " . $dr_namee[$f] . "</td>";
            //echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$f] . "</td>";
            //echo "<td>" . $fave[$f] . "</td>";
            //echo "<td>" . $dayse[$f] . "</td>";
            //echo "</tr>";
            //$r++;
            $f++;
        }
        //for($i=0;$i<count($Names);$i=$i+5)
        //{
        for($i=0;$i<count($dr_ide);$i=$i+5)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td> Dr. " . $dr_namee[$i] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+1] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+2] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+3] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $sub_namee[$i+4] . "</td>";

            echo "<td>  <select  name='perr' >
                        <option  selected=selected>Choose one</option>";
                        foreach($Names as $name) {
                             echo"<option value='$name'>$name</option>";

                        }                            
                        echo "</select></td>";
            //echo "<td>" . $dayse[$i] . "</td>";
            //echo "<td>" . $timing[$i] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

    echo $_SESSION["tt"];

    if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){ 
        echo $_POST['perr'];
    }

?>
</table>

            <input ID="btn2" name="confirm"  type="submit" value="Home">

            </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this solve the first problem and the values appear, but when i wants to read the post value it give me error "undefined index"

Comment: @SalehRefaai where are you defining the field named "confirm"?

Comment: there are rest of code where i put button with name confirm and when i remove echo $_POST['perr']; and put echo 'hi'; it prints hi

Comment: I added my full code to see it and see the submit button . @claudio

Comment: @SalehRefaai you have to insert the table inside the form